# Create a col of Seq[String] values from column a col of Seq[String]

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have this input dataframe:

**inputDF**=

```
+---------------------+
|days (seq[String])   |
+---------------------+
|[sat, sun]           |
|[mon, wed]           |
|[fri ]               |
|[fri, sat]           |
|[mon, sun, sat]      |
+---------------------+
```

I would like to obtain this outputDF containing all exisiting Strings from days column

**outputDF**=

```
+---------------------+----------------------------+
|days (seq[String])   |all days (seq[String])      |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
|[sat, sun]           |[sat, sun, mon, wed, fri]   |
|[mon, wed]           |[sat, sun, mon, wed, fri]   |
|[fri]                |[sat, sun, mon, wed, fri]   |
|[fri, sat]           |[sat, sun, mon, wed, fri]   |
|[mon, sun, sat]      |[sat, sun, mon, wed, fri]   |
+---------------------+----------------------------+
```

How to do that in Scala/Spark please

Comment: Could you use some more data for your example? Right now, no matter what your input `days` is, the output is the same `all days`, so no logic can be derived from your example

Comment: It is intentional to have `all days` column with same values. I would like to have a column of seq[String] containing all identified Strings in `days` column, at least once.

Comment: Is there any use case where `all days`'s output changes? For example, what if the input is empty `[]`? Or what if the input is `[sat, sun, sat]`?

Comment: In my usecase, the `days` column has already distinct values in the Seq[String].
And if it is empty, then no String is taken into account to be added to the final Seq[String] of `all days` column

Comment: Then, is it wrong if we do `dataset.withColumn("all_days", Seq("sat", "sun", "mon", "wed", fri"))`, basically just hardcoding the values?

Comment: We cannot hardcode the value because I need to dynamically discover the values in `days` column. **We do not know in advance what is the content of the `days` column.**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250365/discussion-between-vilalabinot-and-didi-in-the-club).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is our input, and it is called `dataset`:

```
+---------------+
|days           |
+---------------+
|[sat, sun]     |
|[mon, wed]     |
|[fri]          |
|[fri, sat]     |
|[mon, sun, sat]|
+---------------+
```

We can get to this output:

```
+---------------+-------------------------+
|days           |all_days                 |
+---------------+-------------------------+
|[sat, sun]     |[fri, sat, sun, mon, wed]|
|[mon, wed]     |[fri, sat, sun, mon, wed]|
|[fri]          |[fri, sat, sun, mon, wed]|
|[fri, sat]     |[fri, sat, sun, mon, wed]|
|[mon, sun, sat]|[fri, sat, sun, mon, wed]|
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Through the following code:

```scala
// First we want to create a unique ID (if you don't have that already)
dataset = dataset.withColumn("id", lit(1))

// We want to group by the id, and collect all values into an array, then apply distinct
val collected = dataset
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(array_distinct(flatten(collect_set("days"))).as("all_days"))

// We join our main table with the collected data
dataset = dataset
  .join(collected, Seq("id"), "left")
  .drop("id")
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can create another dataset that contains the unique days value then join it back to your initial dataset:

```
import spark.implicits._
val data = Seq(
  Seq("sat", "sun"),
  Seq("mon", "wed"),
  Seq("fri" ),
  Seq("fri", "sat"),
  Seq("mon", "sun", "sat")
)

val df = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data).toDF("days")
val allDf = df.select(explode(col("days")).as("days")).agg(collect_set("days").as("all_days"))
  .withColumn("join_column", lit(1))
df.withColumn("join_column", lit(1)).join(broadcast(allDf), Seq("join_column"), "left").drop("join_column").show(false)


+---------------+-------------------------+
|days           |all_days                 |
+---------------+-------------------------+
|[sat, sun]     |[fri, sun, wed, mon, sat]|
|[mon, wed]     |[fri, sun, wed, mon, sat]|
|[fri]          |[fri, sun, wed, mon, sat]|
|[fri, sat]     |[fri, sun, wed, mon, sat]|
|[mon, sun, sat]|[fri, sun, wed, mon, sat]|
+---------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can collect distinct values and then add it using withColumn

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val data = Seq((Seq("sun", "sun", "mon")),
               (Seq("sun", "tue", "mon")),
               (Seq("fri", "tue")))
val days = data.toDF("days")
val uniqueDays = days.agg(array_distinct(flatten(collect_set("days")))).head()(0)

days.withColumn("all days", lit(uniqueDays)).show(false)
```

Output is:

```
+---------------+--------------------+
|days           |all days            |
+---------------+--------------------+
|[sun, sun, mon]|[fri, tue, sun, mon]|
|[sun, tue, mon]|[fri, tue, sun, mon]|
|[fri, tue]     |[fri, tue, sun, mon]|
+---------------+--------------------+
```